# iOS 7 App Crash EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Works fine on iOS 6

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

My app is crashing in iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.1, its working fine in iOS 6. I are not sure what is causing the issue. I can see that there is some exception thrown but we are not sure where in code is causing that.

Here is the crash report:

```
`{"bundleID":"com.citruspay.citruscash","app_name":"CitrusPayApp","bug_type":"109","name":"CitrusPayApp","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","version":"1.0.0 (1.0.0)"}
Incident Identifier: A5104F94-FDDF-4A0D-8288-9A5DD19D79E5
CrashReporter Key:   e4aaaa407264c5e777d1a0eb326b0cf84daf9fc8
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             CitrusPayApp [16135]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/CD2CA823-E1E7-4923-BDAE-FD17F6DCC8E1/CitrusPayApp.app/CitrusPayApp
Identifier:          com.citruspay.citruscash
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-24 13:14:52.458 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2df76f0b 0x38b4cce7 0x2df7a837 0x2df79137 0x2dec8098 0x15806b 0x12858f 0x128669 0x158c87 0x157c7d 0x2e956117 0x2df41f4f 0x2df41b6b 0x2df3fef3 0x2deaa769 0x2deaa54b 0x32de16d3 0x30809891 0x13d54b 0x3904aab7)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x391011f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391697b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x390b1ff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3850098b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x385196e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38b4cf7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x385171b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38516d13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38b4ce2b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2deaa7db CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2deaa547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x32de16cf GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x3080988d UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  CitrusPayApp                    0x0013d547 0xf6000 + 292167
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3904aab5 start + 1

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390ee804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3903d051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x390372df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390eea50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390ee849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df41625 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df3fd45 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2deaa765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2deaa547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Foundation                      0x2e8ea23d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
7   Foundation                      0x2e95fa0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39168957 _pthread_body + 139
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391688c7 _pthread_start + 99
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2df4551f __CFSocketManager + 483
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39168957 _pthread_body + 139
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391688c7 _pthread_start + 99
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390eea50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x390ee849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df41625 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df3fd45 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2deaa765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2deee387 CFRunLoopRun + 95
6   CoreMotion                      0x2e5694fd 0x2e530000 + 234749
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39168957 _pthread_body + 139
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391688c7 _pthread_start + 99
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39101c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166c1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39166ad8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3adee18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d0d584
    r8: 0x14d6e230    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x30dd29af     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d0d578      lr: 0x391697b7      pc: 0x391011f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xf6000 - 0x279ff7 CitrusPayApp armv7  <5325d189b0473e0688770d1ba176ce11> /var/mobile/Applications/CD2CA823-E1E7-4923-BDAE-FD17F6DCC8E1/CitrusPayApp.app/CitrusPayApp
0x2be96000 - 0x2beb66aa dyld armv7s  <4d05d388718832c99cdd4e74aeb07d51> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2cdfb000 - 0x2cefdfff AVFoundation armv7s  <c88b12b244d13bbd9a8ab681956234e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2cefe000 - 0x2cf26ff4 libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <b92283f0007834c7a52635881be94ab7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2cf27000 - 0x2cf27fff Accelerate armv7s  <58ca068138d93e988a34a0c8c34b0b11> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2cf31000 - 0x2d0fefda vImage armv7s  <9923548d8ed23bb1b1020130b5d38dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2d0ff000 - 0x2d1e1fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <48f7680a8fd83251ad8415bb090408c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2d1e2000 - 0x2d49afff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <2547383dc88d3329827b4d76768915ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2d49b000 - 0x2d509ff7 libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <83036da6f5d9308bb5fad06b2d29bac9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2d50a000 - 0x2d51cff3 libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <addc52a9647f3269965a750366ebed70> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2d51d000 - 0x2d51dfff vecLib armv7s  <4a647b20c3f03490aae530226350a4cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x2d51e000 - 0x2d53effe Accounts armv7s  <73b0639b81fe30d5b2b13628d3df2273> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2d540000 - 0x2d5a7ff3 AddressBook armv7s  <e0051f44c0d0377da85049ff86fbc890> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x2d5a8000 - 0x2d6befff AddressBookUI armv7s  <7a96c5c6a22f3b329d5f434870469175> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x2d815000 - 0x2db31ff0 AudioToolbox armv7s  <42ef392f2082317cbd3857838ab97aaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x2db32000 - 0x2dc38ff0 CFNetwork armv7s  <7f8df6965c623f8d9913dee8c8c9c7b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x2dc39000 - 0x2dc94ff7 CoreAudio armv7s  <34a6461e9ad3380ea9e0405f81aad500> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x2dc95000 - 0x2dcacfff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <0e672bb563ea3c2fb0c6ae0070d00efb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x2dcad000 - 0x2dea1067 CoreData armv7s  <23650924fc293fdf994419f6894720a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x2dea2000 - 0x2dfe5ff0 CoreFoundation armv7s  <747c88b531d53bcbadfbcc953a429ea0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x2dfe6000 - 0x2e10affb CoreGraphics armv7s  <182ccc3a111d360eb5c1e58b4289afb3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x2e10c000 - 0x2e147ff0 libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <1d9c402cc18433db9a72d349876b2fea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x2e149000 - 0x2e153ff8 libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <1efb72c2985332c485d07c5a3784f93b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x2e338000 - 0x2e352ff3 libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <23b82f0d28e238938519439e243ae7a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x2e353000 - 0x2e42cffc CoreImage armv7s  <1eedb55ace133e10bb629fa881c45542> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x2e42d000 - 0x2e47cff7 CoreLocation armv7s  <5d78705a46ab313fa21f1d5ed2f0ce3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x2e4b4000 - 0x2e52fffb CoreMedia armv7s  <d68d0cf856f13ff7ab9418ccd671cd65> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x2e530000 - 0x2e5d8ffb CoreMotion armv7s  <bd402a711091322bb2284be34283973f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x2e5d9000 - 0x2e631ff7 CoreTelephony armv7s  <711db5ac808937b09143f43f11f06422> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x2e632000 - 0x2e6c2ff3 CoreText armv7s  <43e84c5a90fc36a984363965f2d8029b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x2e6c3000 - 0x2e6d2fff CoreVideo armv7s  <b114a9e05c08366b8735a2911defa97b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x2e892000 - 0x2ea7cff3 Foundation armv7s  <b75ca4f9d9b739ef9b16e482db277849> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x2ec5e000 - 0x2ecb4ff3 IOKit armv7s  <1acd39a2052f36cebb9b68f9f1448619> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x2ecb5000 - 0x2eec5ffd ImageIO armv7s  <3234150da2d13945a33c98335e53db80> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x2eec6000 - 0x2f111ff7 JavaScriptCore armv7s  <3d942899969b3c41aa764b228ec6cc65> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x2f1c2000 - 0x2f1c6ff3 MediaAccessibility armv7s  <c87f228e5b18380d837ed901196705c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x2f3c5000 - 0x2f6cbff3 MediaToolbox armv7s  <c3d89d30f78b3077b444a870e89a31a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x2f778000 - 0x2f7dbffe MobileCoreServices armv7s  <1a736ebbc93431c8943cdd93a0a0fdcb> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30223000 - 0x3022bfff OpenGLES armv7s  <1c3e551d0a923b86940ad36a6e682463> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3022d000 - 0x3022dfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <ba661b77360f360b88c3163a02538376> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30232000 - 0x30235ffe libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <38ff1c7f12f83f8bac062e8daf9d4c10> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x30236000 - 0x3023dfff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <2406a4e5c5b437dbb0a3553655ac4951> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3023e000 - 0x3027effc libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <7d912d8e3a453456a6e2d806b59aa448> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30416000 - 0x3055dfff QuartzCore armv7s  <741ee0338b1235aab1550f91a3956041> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x305b7000 - 0x305f9ffb Security armv7s  <cd7187d315eb301e845cfae580ca905f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30749000 - 0x30798fff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <82758c34b29a333bbdfe73e78361e0e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3079b000 - 0x30f0effd UIKit armv7s  <f725ad0982673286911bff834295ec99> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x30f0f000 - 0x30f5dff3 VideoToolbox armv7s  <052e071cd44b3d33abdb0761635ba4be> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x312cf000 - 0x312d3fff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <b4e58fe6256136749b7d54bf07bcbc51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3192f000 - 0x3196dff3 AppSupport armv7s  <0cb23d5c42d530cfa7e43605cf368293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31a64000 - 0x31a6afff AppleSRP armv7s  <e1db5ed3b8e034ce94f260077c96cea8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x31a97000 - 0x31aa3ffb AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <05cf849c0bab37698f93ce58e0cabe0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31aa4000 - 0x31ac0ffd AssistantServices armv7s  <486d8370b0a33d08802dc9353d240dfa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x31aed000 - 0x31af0ffd BTLEAudioController armv7s  <f420608b2d7538bb88491b34501a36f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x31af1000 - 0x31b16ffb BackBoardServices armv7s  <eef3e744484a386ca351b8feb000eb37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x31b19000 - 0x31b1effc BluetoothManager armv7s  <9d86b542e884374f9845e9a53139abd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x31b1f000 - 0x31b43ff7 Bom armv7s  <af79573fee7d364da59eed3fabe2f645> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31be4000 - 0x31becfff CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <9825d6ad32163fcd8f2f56dbf274de62> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31bed000 - 0x31cc9ff5 Celestial armv7s  <b8805a7aa0bb34cb9d0a41cf8e7b8875> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31cd6000 - 0x31cdbfff CertUI armv7s  <68968485501f35c09203bd9e045bbcd0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31e18000 - 0x31e23fff CommonUtilities armv7s  <f477748e4ac03e91b3a2769b59dc0dc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x31e24000 - 0x31e28fff CommunicationsFilter armv7s  <87e7685b12ac375aa482a7a31cd28517> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x31eb9000 - 0x31ebbfff ConstantClasses armv7s  <aab583ee29ff3ed7a9ad2bddfbc9bcde> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x31efb000 - 0x31efdfff CoreAUC armv7s  <77474784f35a35718fa5c6bd358ec659> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x32192000 - 0x321b0fff CoreServicesInternal armv7s  <29b0b6f5421c3753a2c42ef2c1ef4892> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x321b1000 - 0x321b2ffd CoreSurface armv7s  <3445b07c2bca372cbe202fec0a9aa86f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32259000 - 0x322b5ffd CoreUI armv7s  <3fdd5b6ee0b03774a8a67554e8a3c3ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x322b6000 - 0x3230aff6 CoreUtils armv7s  <2cd95e7adf393d0e9656dcaee71b8298> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x3230b000 - 0x32310ffc CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <d3f693f332fe3f46bd3b9f582a3e6ba0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x324dc000 - 0x324f2ffe DataAccessExpress armv7s  <d267039af5923039bb15d53806a16edc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x324fc000 - 0x32512fff DataDetectorsCore armv7s  <cf924ead1d493e6ba226987d4028a25c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x32514000 - 0x3252cfff DataDetectorsUI armv7s  <22816c9fbeea3f73ae6a7a1675a8f4d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x3252d000 - 0x32531ffb DataMigration armv7s  <24479dd9d49a354da98e6a0ce861558b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32536000 - 0x32537fff DiagnosticLogCollection armv7s  <92f04186ee463c60a309eb847f65466e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x32538000 - 0x32551ffa DictionaryServices armv7s  <b32f1de0807532e2944c9365d543b542> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x32570000 - 0x3258dff4 EAP8021X armv7s  <cf7974147c9f35a3b446d4efd21fb925> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x32596000 - 0x325a1fff ExFAT armv7s  <a50c8c49cc703ad59b3caff9dfe105e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExFAT.framework/ExFAT
0x325a2000 - 0x325b2fff FTAWD armv7s  <d11cec9c3a7237e8b708f168699cb5d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTAWD.framework/FTAWD
0x325b6000 - 0x325e0ff7 FTServices armv7s  <d3c08d2b370c35808e1db8d480c148cb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x325e1000 - 0x329fcff7 FaceCore armv7s  <72642f324b7639faa8206f00a953a573> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x32c2b000 - 0x32dd7ffa GeoServices armv7s  <1d0e1ac52cc636e2a6ff9d130bc9108d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x32dd8000 - 0x32deeff7 GraphicsServices armv7s  <3b6c1bed029a36809c005aded6358ae2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32f78000 - 0x32facfff IDS armv7s  <e824f1e917a33b0db3e675a66f1c6f28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x3301c000 - 0x3302dfff IDSFoundation armv7s  <dc1e6fe7ea2b3390b00c1c350c331dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x3302e000 - 0x33092ff7 IMAVCore armv7s  <d8efc05aa81631249ba04db48f85aa6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x33093000 - 0x33120fff IMCore armv7s  <37d286ade2fd3ec2984b722cc42a18db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x331a0000 - 0x331fafff IMFoundation armv7s  <1fe1f17117fd346e872606e1fbaf958f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33204000 - 0x3320bffa IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <3ab45fc088e63f2583325fb2a3d793ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3320c000 - 0x33211fff IOSurface armv7s  <231684abf3443db1b2dde09b82f5bdba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3325e000 - 0x33263fff IncomingCallFilter armv7s  <bd3e15ae29be33108b38be2a371a7d7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IncomingCallFilter.framework/IncomingCallFilter
0x3334f000 - 0x333cafff ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <ff4aa3ba73fa3c6295d84a663b7230ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x333cb000 - 0x333ccfff Marco armv7s  <a6d37d7ca6de35abbe32371d5713347c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x333cd000 - 0x33446fff MediaControlSender armv7s  <ecca229a940e30c0b98d635758a10433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x33485000 - 0x33492ffb MediaRemote armv7s  <9d9e2ea66c0836ab886b38beb1b05532> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x335f7000 - 0x33603fff MobileAsset armv7s  <40c56824686c35c9bc6a53e48696e8ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x33627000 - 0x3362fffc MobileBluetooth armv7s  <8dd3363b6e2330d9b0eb427f5010b199> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3364a000 - 0x3364dffd MobileInstallation armv7s  <7e644fec475d31c2bde3c0a9249ea3c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3364e000 - 0x33658fff MobileKeyBag armv7s  <e94a6746becd36ef89f18d8f62e3ef80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33680000 - 0x33683fff MobileSystemServices armv7s  <1bc1a98c34d5398ca9ff7d2a6cd65243> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x336a2000 - 0x336adffc MobileWiFi armv7s  <cf996c9ae1063228918d8b7767679eea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33949000 - 0x3394efff Netrb armv7s  <11576949484a3405881d436920cf495c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x3394f000 - 0x33954ffe NetworkStatistics armv7s  <04f1b60537e03715934f8cdbb2992fbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x3397a000 - 0x3397cffd OAuth armv7s  <e5d7ef5ec520310187365df875a549ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x340d3000 - 0x3410eff6 OpenCL armv7s  <b6fbdfb3287d3fbfb5286db2871e20f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x346b4000 - 0x346dbff7 PersistentConnection armv7s  <199be1a72cf136e38f3e97f918225ac3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34af7000 - 0x34b2aff2 PhysicsKit armv7s  <eabb43d582b434e7a07113dc75526237> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x34c21000 - 0x34c58ff7 PrintKit armv7s  <07cdb8fa73f638878da43cb85ecc6525> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x34c5c000 - 0x34ce2fff ProofReader armv7s  <c51b02fd95b5374a92d5f442914fd833> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34ce3000 - 0x34cedfff ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <e51109e38b5e3229941c644bd3c1fda0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34d1f000 - 0x34d93fff Quagga armv7s  <14d6711448dd35da93958349e88c67bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x34ed4000 - 0x34f59ffb SAObjects armv7s  <b41c35cc73f13f53ae5e4f4cb261fef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x35086000 - 0x3509bff3 SpringBoardServices armv7s  <c57673fe5697361292f6d98f0e42b43a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x352df000 - 0x35401fff StoreServices armv7s  <cb1f0a915435356daef1d6224e84d771> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x354b1000 - 0x354b3ffc TCC armv7s  <c954ee084fc138cd9e1efd673fcc1db6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x35507000 - 0x35528ff7 TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <89a81f2b2d00390f94886d091df8c370> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x35529000 - 0x35b50ffd KBLayouts_iPad.dylib armv7s  <45ca29f3151931a1a112612235605c35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/KBLayouts_iPad.dylib
0x35b51000 - 0x35b84ffc TextInput armv7s  <aa0e49d7392f391184c9eeb39a4d3bf0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35e07000 - 0x35ec7ff5 UIFoundation armv7s  <c451f67b37fe34b1837080f77df2c608> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x35edf000 - 0x35ee2ffe UserFS armv7s  <8c69a37146f53c20b27515d9081b585e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x3630c000 - 0x36329fff VoiceServices armv7s  <508ca2f579c73bccb386602a7188c835> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x36387000 - 0x36e36ffb WebCore armv7s  <62a2855ff9ba3663a05c495a1e6083a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36e37000 - 0x36ef7ff7 WebKit armv7s  <4679be02e7e63e5697b74338046f39c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x37042000 - 0x3704affe XPCObjects armv7s  <bd5f2f198bfc300886e389b6504c3d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3804d000 - 0x38054fff libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <6783339bc8c0357a88c9f342125cfd4f> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x38251000 - 0x38267fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <1b03911a248832d5b24075ac2a3edfe3> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x3827d000 - 0x38292ff9 libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <47eca5e4f72f38459912efd50f7560a9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x382b0000 - 0x382b1fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <eabeb73e81a8362d8e62af1bd466b876> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x38320000 - 0x3834eff1 libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7s  <a0a1a8c4002a3b3095de44ab6ef68876> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x3849d000 - 0x384a9fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <fc1cbfcbdd563d02a601aabed2bd7d15> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x384aa000 - 0x384b3fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <20bf7a7ab7e73d4c8453b1c86a7c5e3d> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x384b4000 - 0x384ffff4 libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <72615c78ae5f39dcbafa740d87035caf> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x38500000 - 0x3851affe libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <b20ecbadceba32fe8f990af252b6abba> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3852a000 - 0x38531ffb libcupolicy.dylib armv7s  <239f9438dced35b5957016d6354a6001> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x38578000 - 0x38665ff1 libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <cd99d67497e23173bfaf7eac2409774a> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x38666000 - 0x387b7fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <9e6bead09e6e3f6284775099f2af03e2> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x387bf000 - 0x387bfffd liblangid.dylib armv7s  <3cca7b6ef834379b82d4a032f99cdfc8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x387c0000 - 0x387caffc liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <de62a6a0b6ef33b59d9c53d4eaeb4013> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x38b0c000 - 0x38b20fff libmis.dylib armv7s  <7da8703c8950371ca3bad4d8c34bd892> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x38b49000 - 0x38ce89df libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <bf3e22d3067133989a99a9bf07c4e8f8> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x38db0000 - 0x38dc5ff3 libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <880b294be76f3f9989247ca125ad3550> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x38dee000 - 0x38e85ffc libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <584eaf4090783a64b8a33125a6a976bd> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x38e86000 - 0x38ed3ff1 libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <6428df9b541c3ffbb23c393b3b1280e9> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x38ed4000 - 0x38efaffb libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <40c283e2258a330d9ff9799da0a1d2bb> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x38efe000 - 0x38fb1fff libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <1a18ebeae7253959b9cfe286550809a8> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x38fb2000 - 0x38fd3fff libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <cf7ad714d218330087df8422a129e027> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x38fd4000 - 0x38fe0ff7 libz.1.dylib armv7s  <578def3dfb6e3180b5f9d0cdacfea7ab> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x38fe1000 - 0x38fe5ffa libcache.dylib armv7s  <5552b722402630c39069717fce563238> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x38fe6000 - 0x38feeff3 libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <a6695b43e12f338c9dc0906d8bfed65e> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x38fef000 - 0x38ff3ff8 libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <cfdcad14d51d30a9a511af272ba560ac> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x38ff4000 - 0x38ffafff libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <553c4af79d1e30bdafc06af9cf757caf> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x38ffb000 - 0x39034ff3 libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <3078b6192ac6371eb233dfa9b483728b> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x39035000 - 0x39048ff9 libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <724a779782af35d5b686b90ae55712be> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x39049000 - 0x3904afff libdyld.dylib armv7s  <1e6f4480b0cc3b288ca16260858dd0be> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3904b000 - 0x3904bfff libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <cd6879d7aab538188885a690d4867364> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3904c000 - 0x39052fff liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <e2ecc7065f99385486a316b484915504> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x39053000 - 0x39056ffc libmacho.dylib armv7s  <af571f784f753dc883752ab57de8d850> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
`
```

Comment: Please symbolicate the stacktrace.

Comment: You could add exception breakpoint in xcode. And it will show you the place.

Comment: @user249605 : Do u got the solution? app is crashing some time.

Comment: @Coder_A_D: Haven't got any solution